# Estimote iBeacon error: Service not available

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

I am working on Estimote iBeacon project which will display properties of iBeacons. Now, my app shows the many properties of iBeacon but I want to change iBeacons major and minor values. When I change iBeacon's major or minor values, error message comes, which is "Service not available.".Here is my code, anybody can help me?

Thank you.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Enter Major Value", @"") message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"") otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"Write", @""), nil];
            alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
            UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
            textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", [beacon.major unsignedShortValue]];
            textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
            textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
            alertView.tag = 50;
            [alertView show];
        }
            break;
}
```

---

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    switch (alertView.tag)
    {
        case 50:
            switch (buttonIndex)
        {
            case 1:
                [self writeMajor:[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text integerValue] completion:^(unsigned short value, NSError *error)
                 {

                 }
                 ];
}
```

---

```
- (void)writeMajor:(unsigned short)major completion:(ESTUnsignedShortCompletionBlock)completion
{
    [beacon writeMajor:major completion:^(unsigned short value, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             NSLog(@"%s: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error);
             UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Could Not Write Major Value", @"") message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"") otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alertView show];
         }
         else
         {

         }
     }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to modify any of the beacon's settings, you need to connect to the beacon first:

[`ESTBeacon connect`](http://estimote.github.io/iOS-SDK/Classes/ESTBeacon.html#//api/name/connect)

*Note that this is an async method and you need to wait till the [`beaconConnectionDidSucceeded:`](http://estimote.github.io/iOS-SDK/Protocols/ESTBeaconDelegate.html#//api/name/beaconConnectionDidSucceeded:) method of the `ESTBeaconDelegate` gets called before you can start writing to beacon.*

One prerequsities to this step: with Estimote Beacons, only apps authorized by the owner of the beacon can connect to it. You authenticate the app with the [`ESTConfig setupAppID:andAppToken:`](http://estimote.github.io/iOS-SDK/Classes/ESTConfig.html#//api/name/setupAppID:andAppToken:). The ID and token are created and retrieved from the Estimote Cloud web dashboard at http://cloud.estimote.com.

Comment: I didn't use these methods, after using I think I can change beacon's values. Sounds good. Thank you.

Comment: Hi again @heypiotr I asked a question about kontakt iBeacon. It is same problem with answered my question. I couldn't access all properties of iBeacons. Here is the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694029/get-properties-of-kontakt-ibeacon Can you help me?